# Issue with ParentForm's property changing detection

Tags: vb.net, user-controls, visual-studio-2017

I am working on a custom `TitleBar` (`UserControl`). What I want to do is to **detect** when `ParentForm`'s `Text` property is changing by developer in **Design Time** and then **update** `TitleBar`'s `Text` property.

Before I start looking for this on the web, I had add a `Timer` into my `UserControl` to do this "work". Something like this...

```
Private Sub Timer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer.Tick
    FormTitle_Label.Text = Me.ParentForm.Text
End Sub
```

Then I realized that this isn't the most appropriate approach. So I found something like this...

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnCreateControl()
    MyBase.OnCreateControl()
    AddHandler Me.FindForm.TextChanged, AddressOf ParentForm_TextChanged 
    FormTitle_Label.Text = Me.FindForm.Text
End Sub

Private Sub ParentForm_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    FormTitle_Label.Text = Me.FindForm.Text
End Sub
```

It partly works but, everytime I **rebuild** or **remove** and **re add** my `UserControl` into a `Form`, when I try to change the `Text` property of my `ParentForm`, I get the error, `Property value is not valid. Details: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`. If I **close** and **reopen** my project then it works again, but until I **rebuild** it or **remove** and **re add** my `UserControl`. Any idea why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to test value of Me.FindForm to Nothing before accesing it's property. Creation of control does not guarantee that it's present on form already.

Try using <s>OnBindingContextChanged</s> **OnParentChanged** to track adding/removing your control to parent container. <s>But I'm not sure if it works in design time as well.</s>

**EDIT** Added full control code

```
Public Class SimonetosTitleBar
    Inherits Control

    Private fText As String = "Default title"
    Private WithEvents fOwnerForm As Form

    Protected Overrides Sub OnParentChanged(e As EventArgs)
        MyBase.OnParentChanged(e)
        fOwnerForm = FindForm()
        fOwnerForm_TextChanged()
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(e As PaintEventArgs)
        MyBase.OnPaint(e)
        e.Graphics.DrawString(fText, Font, SystemBrushes.ControlText, Point.Empty)
    End Sub

    Private Sub fOwnerForm_TextChanged() Handles fOwnerForm.TextChanged
        If fOwnerForm Is Nothing Then
            fText = "Default title"
        Else
            fText = fOwnerForm.Text
        End If
        Invalidate()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: I tried some things but nothing... Can you give me an example of what you exactly mean? Maybe my knowledge level is the problem...

Comment: Look at the edited answer. WithEvents does some magic instead of AddHandler/RemoveHandler. And there's OnPaint instead of your label to avoid designer file for demo purposes.